# Missing xml tag SVG file (using Graphviz dot.exe)

Tags: xampp, mediawiki, graphviz, dot

My config is:
- Windows Vista
- XAMPP 1.7.1
- Media Wiki + Semantic MW
- an extension that uses Graphviz to create a SVG
- Graphviz 2.26.3 (install dir c:\graphviz.....)

Everything works fine but the problem is: the xml tag
'image xlink:href="some_image.png"....'
is missing from the SVG file created using a Media Wiki php page.

This is done by:
$cmdlinesvg = wfEscapeShellArg($cmd).' -T svg '.wfEscapeShellArg($src).' -o '.wfEscapeShellArg($svg);
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Exec($cmdlinesvg);

I've created a batch file that executes the same command line:

c:\graphviz2.26.3\bin\dot.exe -T svg filename.dot -o filename.svg

and if I run it manually it works, and the xml tag appears.

Anyone knows what is the problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

The problem is related to the image path that is in the .DOT file.

If you run the command line manually, the image path doesn't need to be a full path. 
You can have only: shapefile="some_image.png"

If you run the command inside php code, the image path HAS to be a full path. 
So you must have: shapefile="C:\xampp......\some_image.png"

Another problem arises: the resulting .SVG file doesn't show the images.

If you right-click and open the .SVG file with the browser (ie Firefox), the images are ok.
But, again, through a php page, the images are lost. 
Solution: edit the .SVG file (this is XML) to change the paths. 
On the original .SVG file we have: 
On the modified .SVG file we must have:

PS: I'm doing my master thesis, so this is for a particular problem, but still I hope it helps someone.